# Wireshark Remote Interfaces error message while connecting

Tags: remote-access, remoting, wireshark

I what to connect with wireshark remote interface to an other computer. On the computer runs pcap. But it don't work. Do someone know the reason and a solution?

Errormessage:

I get the message: "Can't get list of interfaces: Login fault. Unknown user or password"

I have tried the following:

- I have checked Password and User, they were valid and the user is a domain user with admin rights.
- I have tried yo make a remote interface to the local machine where wireshark is running and this works.
- I used the Port: 2002 and there is no virusscanner.

How can I check that I can use the Port: 2002 ?

Is there an other common port like 2002 ?

Where is the reason for the error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

You have to use a local user of the remote computer with admin rights, a domain user won't work with rdpcap :-)